# Storing timeinterval to nsuserdefaults in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, nsuserdefaults, nstimeinterval

I am trying to save the current time of a song in the willmovefromview method so that the song can play on at the same time when scene will start again in the didmovetoview method, But I do not know what code to use to store a NSTimeinterval

My piece of code to store and get the current time(not working: NSTimeinterval is not convertible to Int())

```
backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("musictime")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime, forKey: "musictime")
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you "cmd-click" on `NSTimeInterval` in the Xcode source file you'll see that
`NSTimeInterval` is defined as a typealias for `Double`:

```
typealias NSTimeInterval = Double
```

So you have to use `doubleForKey` and `setDouble` to get and set it in the user defaults:

```
backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("musictime")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime, forKey: "musictime")
```

Answer (score 1):

As NSTimeInterval is actually a Double (as @Martin R has already pointed out) you have to do the following to store your value:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime, forKey: "someKey")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

To get back your value you have to do the following:

```
backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = NSUserDefaults.doubleForKey("someKey")
```